# Send event to SMS that can be saved to a phones calendar or reminders

Tags: events, mobile, automation, sms

Is it possible to send a calendar event to a mobile phone via SMS that can then be saved to the phones calendar or reminders.

I have noticed that on most smartphones, numbers, web addresses, addresses, and events will be underlined so a user can choose to save these items to their calendar. This also happens in SMS to a degree, but you can not have a date such as dentist appointment 8th Feb 2012 appear as an event that can be saved.

Is there a way to make this happen simply with regular software (eg iphone sms) or does it require an new SMS service/application to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don´t search this, but Yes, it´s possible. You need [send binary messages](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/23e93d2d-0f25-4799-9b03-1ec9b5cf775a/Smart_Messaging_FAQ_v2_0.pdf.html).